# Apply Media query inside a method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, media-queries

I have a method which is called on button click.And I have media queries to set position right.

```
method(){
          $(".window").animate(
            {
             right: 420 // apply media query here
            },5000)
        }
```

I would like to apply specific media query based on type of device inside this method. Is it possible ? Thank you.

Comment: it's possible, but probably not necessary, can you show a example?

Comment: context here is like apply dynamic position right based on device ..

Comment: IIRC all media query can also be checked in javascript. so just check them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some specific `.class` and apply to it media query in your css.

Comment: @media YOUR_CONDITIONS {
        .class {
            YOUR_STYLES
        }
    }

And just apply class to element in js script.

Comment: i mean how to apply class in js file as its inside animate method